# Webform redirect to login before submit

Tags: webforms

I am creating a webform for my users to submit it but i have one question.
How to redirect users to login before they submit a webform?

Comment: instead of [You must login to view this form.] need to be a redirection to the login page.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Login Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/login_redirect) module. It should do what you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a custom implementation of [hook_node_access](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7) so your users can see the node and then probably [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to hide the form if not [user_is_logged_in()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_is_logged_in/7)